# How to deploy docker application having a docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm learning docker and have some difficulties understanding how to deploy an app composed of multiple containers. If each container can be stored on Dockerhub or somewhere else, then where should I store docker-compose that binds all the containers together?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/docker/app

Answer (score 0):

You can store it wherever you want. You just have to create file docker-compose and then run it by `docker-compose up` command, it will find your docker images in your docker and starts containers for them.